# Unable to decompress the data compressed using Brotli in swift

Tags: ios, swift, compression, brotli

I am getting the compressed data in API response. This data is compressed using Brotli algorithm. I am using the extension methods from https://gist.github.com/insidegui/0338b6cff4454ecaa24c315b8e2a11fd.

I have replaced the code from catch block

```
catch {
    // Try legacy decompression if modern decompression fails
    return try gunzipped()
}
```

with `fatalError("Error")` for now.

If I am compress the string & then decompress it using the extension method given in above gist locally, this is working for me successfully as below

```
let jsonString: String = "{\"name\":\"iOSDev\", \"age\":30}" // or "Hello World"
let inputData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)

let compressedData = try inputData?.compressed()
print("Compressed: \(String(describing: compressedData))")

let decompressedData = try compressedData?.decompressed()
print("Decompressed: \(String(describing: decompressedData))")

let decompressedString = String(decoding: decompressedData ?? Data(), as: UTF8.self)
print("Decompressed String -> \(decompressedString)")
```

Output:

```
Compressed: Optional(31 bytes)
Decompressed: Optional(27 bytes)
Decompressed String -> {"name":"iOSDev", "age":30}
```

When I am trying to decompress data received from API response, this always fails with fatalError.
I am using below code to decompress the data received from API response

```
let serverResponse = "Cw2AeyJuYW1lIjoiaU9TRGV2IiwgImFnZSI6MzB9Aw=="
let inputData = serverResponse(using: .utf8)
let decompressedData = try inputData?.decompressed()
print("Decompressed: \(String(describing: decompressedData))")
let decompressedString = String(decoding: decompressedData ?? Data(), as: UTF8.self)
print("Decompressed String -> \(decompressedString)")
```

I am not able to figure out what's going wrong here. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Replace `fatalError("Error")` with `fatalError("Error: \(error)")` so you can see the actual cause of the issue.

Comment: The data you receive seems to be base64, shouldn't you decode it as such first?

Comment: I got it worked using https://github.com/f-meloni/SwiftBrotli it decompressed nicely `serverResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SwiftBrotli](https://github.com/f-meloni/SwiftBrotli) for that. After adding the Package with SPM:

```
import SwiftBrotli

let serverResponse = "Cw2AeyJuYW1lIjoiaU9TRGV2IiwgImFnZSI6MzB9Aw=="
let result = brotli.decompress(serverResponse.data(using: .utf8)!)
switch result {
case .success(let success):
    print("Success: \(success)")
    print(String(data: success, encoding: .utf8))
case .failure(let failure):
    print("Error result2: \(failure)")
}
```

Output:

```
$>Success: 27 bytes
$>Optional("{\"name\":\"iOSDev\", \"age\":30}")
```